# Google Tango Tablet and Google Play Services C++ API

Tags: google-project-tango

I'm trying to integrate Google Play Services (with C++ API) in our game, but I'm struggling with a crash happening on Google Tango Tablet, android 4.2.2. The crash does not happen on any other device.

```
01-27 23:35:47.761: E/GamesNativeSDK(32045): Can't find com/google/android/gms/games/Games.Achievements: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no type "Lcom/google/android/gms/games/achievement/Achievements;" found and so no field "Achievements" could be found in class "Lcom/google/android/gms/games/Games;" or its superclasses.
```

All Google apps from Google Play and the system are up to date. What could be the problem here?

Comment: I have absolutely no clue about google play e.t.c, but `"Lcom/google/android/gms/games/achievement/Achievements;"` seems to be very strange, as 'L' appear inside string. May be you meant `L"com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/Achievements;"`

Comment: Project Tango Dev kit is on KitKat 4.4.2. also remember to update you GMS version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It also crashed on me too, it's related libart on kitkat, we haven't figured out exactly why, but a temp solution is to switch the system to delvik.

Go to Settings->Developer options->Select runtime